# SQL String query

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

i have this insert query im tryin to do but it isn't working. no matter how many variations, and variations of variations i try, it always has a problem with my code.

```
Set rstSimple = cnnSimple.Execute("insert into SALT (Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, ActivationCode, TransactionID, ClientID) VALUES (<%=Request.QueryString(payer_email)%>, <%=Request.QueryString(payer_email)%>, <%=Request.QueryString(first_name)%>, <%=Request.QueryString(last_name)%>, <%=Request.QueryString(hash)%>, <%=Request.QueryString(txn_id)%>, <%=Request.QueryString(client_id)%>)")
```

I don't understand what its problem is: it keeps saying:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0409'

Unterminated string constant

/thanks.asp, line 62

Set rstSimple = cnnSimple.Execute("insert into SALT (Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, ActivationCode, TransactionID, ClientID) VALUES (<%=Request.QueryString(payer_email)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Note: VBScript & ASP.

Can somebody please help me figure this out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the parameters you're passing to [`Request.QueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(VS.90).aspx) should be enclosed in quotes:

```
Request.QueryString("payer_email")
```

---

**UPDATE:** Yes, and as [@PHPology suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369708/sql-string-query/3369737#3369737), you should remove the `<% %>` and simply use string concatenation with `&`.

Try it like this:

```
Set rstSimple = cnnSimple.Execute("insert into SALT (Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, ActivationCode, TransactionID, ClientID) VALUES ('" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("first_name") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("last_name") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("hash") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("txn_id") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("client_id") & "')")
```

---

Although not related to the problem, your query also appears to be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).

Comment: That's what I assumed at first. But not, it just gives me a different error. If I remember correctly, it was: "Expected end of line character". But like I said, it has a problem with everything.

Comment: Thank you. Your update worked, mostly. Now I just keep getting this error: Invalid column name 'Email'. Which makes me think that there is no Email column in the table, but even after I add one, it still bring up that same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place quotes around your <%=Request.QueryString(xyz)%> expressions, and your parameter names, and as you're in script, you don't do <%= %>. e.g. as below:

```
insert into ... VALUES ('" &  Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "', ...)
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the full statement:

```
Set rstSimple = cnnSimple.Execute("insert into SALT (Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, ActivationCode, TransactionID, ClientID) VALUES ('" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "','" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "','" & Request.QueryString("first_name") & "','" & Request.QueryString("last_name") & "','" & Request.QueryString("hash") & "','" & Request.QueryString("txn_id") & "','" & Request.QueryString("client_id") & "')")
```

This comes with the usual BEWARE caveats about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing...

```
"foo <%=bar%> foo"
```

...try this instead:

```
"foo" & bar & "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your `<% %>` as you are already in ASP script mode.
it should be something like this for your values

```
'"& Request.QueryString("payer_email")&"', '"& Request.QueryString("first_name")&"', etc, etc
```

Comment: Thanks. But now it says: Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ee'

Expected ')'

/thanks.asp, line 62

Answer (score 0):

This isn't answering your question, but note that for string fields you will also need to quote the strings, i.e.

```
VALUES ('<%=Request.QueryString(payer_email)%>',
```

Your code is also very prone to SQL injection attacks - this will be an issue if your system is internet facing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code:

- You are using server tags (`<%= %>`) in the server code.
- You don't have quotation marks around the query string key names.
- You don't have apostrophes around the string values in the query.
- The string values are not encoded, so the query is wide open for SQL injection attacks.

You need a function to encode the strings, this works for MS Access and MS SQL Server:

```
Function SqlEncode(str)
  SqlEncode = Replace(str, "'", "''")
End Function
```

Then you use that on the string values in the query:

```
Set rstSimple = cnnSimple.Execute( _
  "insert into SALT " & _
  "(Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, ActivationCode, TransactionID, ClientID) VALUES (" & _
  "'" & SqlEncode(Request.QueryString("payer_email")) & "', " & _
  "'" & SqlEncode(Request.QueryString("payer_email")) & "', " & _
  "'" & SqlEncode(Request.QueryString("first_name")) & "', " & _
  "'" & SqlEncode(Request.QueryString("last_name")) & "', " & _
  "'" & SqlEncode(Request.QueryString("hash")) & "', " & _
  "'" & SqlEncode(Request.QueryString("txn_id")) & "', " & _
  "'" & SqlEncode(Request.QueryString("client_id")) & "'" & _
  ")")
```